# Call to undefined function add_action() wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to WordPress plugins, however I have created a simple one which adds custom JavaScript to my page headers.

When I run the plugin on my WordPress admin page on my localhost, it works perfectly (as in it does what it should), but I have an error with the plugin in my IDE (phpStorm).

The error I get is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   add_action() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website1\wp-content\plugins\jade-plugin\jade-plugin.php:12
>   Stack trace: thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website1\wp-content\plugins\jade-plugin\jade-plugin.php
>   on line 12
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action()
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website1\wp-content\plugins\jade-plugin\jade-plugin.php:12
>   Stack trace: thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website1\wp-content\plugins\jade-plugin\jade-plugin.php
>   on line 12
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

I have no idea what could be causing this error but I think it has something to do with the files in my directory.

I also want to upload this plugin to WordPress.org for our family business but when I try to upload the plugin I get the following error:

> The plugin has no name. Add a Plugin Name: line to your main plugin
>   file and upload the plugin again.

Here is my plugin so far:

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Plugin Name: InSite
     * Plugin URI: http://localhost
     * Description: Adds javascript
     * Version: 1.0
     * Author: Jade
     * License: GPL2
     */

    /* This function adds two lines of javascript to the page header */

    add_action('wp_head', 'addHeader');

    function addHeader()
    {
        ?>
        <script 
    src="http://app.insitesoftware.co.za:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js">
    </script>
        <script src="http://app.insitesoftware.co.za:8080/client.js">
    </script>

<?php
    }

    ;

    ?>
```

Any help would be so appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use wordpress coding standards and functions, The hook to include JavaScript should be `wp_enqueue_scripts` not `wp_head`. Here's the snippet function to do this. And refer [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#comment-274) for more details

```
function slug_cssinvolve() {

        //for custom script
        wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );
        //for library

        wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slug_cssinvolve');
```